# JQuery statusCode 404 - how to get jqXhr url?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a jquery ajax statuscode function to handle a 404...  another Stack Overflow answer states that in the success method, this.url gives the url for the request... however, this doesn't seem to be the case for my statusCode handler.  Any ideas?  Nothing that I can see in documentation about how to get the url for the request.

My ajax option object looks roughly like this  (may have missed off a brace when trimming out code not relevant to this question)

```
;(function($) {
    var defaultSettings = {
     // ... other plugin specific settings
    ajaxOptions:
    {
                    cache:false,
                    context:$(this),
                    statusCode: {
                        404:function(xhr) {

                      // this line...  this.url is always undefined  (so is xhr.url)
                            $('#body').append('<div class="errordisplay">Content not found' + (this.url?': ' + this.url:'') + '</div>');

                    // ... do other stuff

                            return false;

                        }
                    }
            }
}
```

Comment: Are you passing something in the `context` option to `$.ajax()`?

Comment: [`this.url` should work](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/f3XTn/). You might need to post more of your code.

Comment: this ajaxOption object is the default options for a custom jquery plugin, so I have "context:$(this)"  ... question code updated with more detail

Comment: @Nathan, your use of `context` is the problem, as it overrides the default object used as the context for the call to `statusCode`. Since it is specified in `ajaxOptions`, it will be hard to provide the URL as an additional property. You will probably have to store the URL somewhere else, maybe in the element your plugin applies to.

Comment: @Frédéric - Thanks so much  - very helpful :)  Add that as the answer and I'll accept it!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The default context for AJAX event handlers (i.e. the object bound to `this` in the handlers) indeed exposes an `url` property because it is a mix between `$.ajaxSettings` and the arguments passed to [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

However, in your case, you're overriding that default context by passing `$(this)` in the `context` option. Moreover, doing that in `ajaxOptions` means it will not be easy to extend that object with the current URL.

I would suggest associating the URL with the element your plugin is enhancing before the AJAX call, using [data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/) or similar.

Answer (score 32):

You could modify the request & settings objects before sending with following code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
        jqXHR.url = settings.url;
    }
});
```

Then access `xhr.url` in the `statusCode` callback. It should work.

Comment: Works for me and allows to log the url for debug purposes.

Comment: And if it redirects in process?

Comment: @Elaman The browser handles redirect transparently, so it should work for 301/302 responses.